# Python Post Request works, but the same PHP (CURL) does not work

Tags: python, php, curl, post, python-requests

I was trying to write the same post request via php as i did in python. In python it works well, while in php it does not even reach the server at all. This is php 7.4. Also I can access the server http://someip:2080/api/
via browser. So http://someip:2080/api/ is a public IP, I can even access via browser, so it should work from anywhere.

PHP code:

```
$payload = array(
'data' => 'data0',
);

// Setup cURL
$ch = curl_init('http://someip:2080/api/');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
),
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($payload)
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);


if($response === FALSE){
   die(curl_error($ch));
}
```

and python code:

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
resp = requests.post("http://someip:2080/api/" , data = json.dumps(allparams),  headers=headers)
thepara = resp.json()
```

I have no idea what is wrong I tried around 10 ways to make post request from php and nothing worked.

Comment: "it does not even reach the server at all" then you probably have a network problem.

Comment: I tried from python and the same ip and you are correct it does not work. So it is some kind of network error. I just do not know what would is the cause, because I am able to access this URL from browser.

Comment: I guess it is problem that port 2080 is likely already used by cpanell:

Comment: 2080  CalDAV and CardDAV (SSL)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the port 2080 was already occupied on a cpanel. So the solution is to :

1. Change port to lets say 9999 which is not occupied
2. Allow the port in WHM firewall, under IPv4 Port Settings (in WHM - ConfigServer Security & Firewall ) or tell admin to do this for you.